# Maximising the height of a div with surrounding elements of variable height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a div that I'd like to maximise the size of, within a parent that's based on a 100vh.

The problem being that I have two `p` divs that can also change their height based on the width of the window, leading to a varying size.

Now the quick and dirty solution might simply be to run a jQuery snippet to detect the sizes of the parent `div` and `p` divs and set the div's height based on these, running the function on `doc.ready` and on `window.onresize`.

But that feels unnecessary, and I'm wondering if there's a neater solution using only CSS that I'm unaware of?

I've set a simplified, but non-working version of the problem below to see if you can get a clearer idea than what I'm referring to.

Any tips would be great, thanks!

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, san-serif;
}

#parent{
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
}

p{
  font-size: 40px; 
  background: yellow;
 }

#p1{
  top: 0;
}

#p2{
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

div{
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <p id="p1">Long block that only appears on the top</p>
  <div>Maximising Div</div>
  <p id="p2">Long block that only appears on the bottom</p>
</div>
```

Comment: have you checked out flexbox? I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking well enough to propose that as an answer, but I think that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Flex box gives you this functionality - depends on what kind of browser support you need. Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp. I can do an example if you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with `flexbox`.

Since there are a lot of resources about how to use `flexbox`, it will not be included in the scope of this answer. However, I'll explain the basics so that you can understand what is going on here.

1. You define a container, in this case `#parent` with the property
   `display: flex;`, this makes it a flex-container.
2. This container's child elements are now flex-items, in your case the
   `<p>` elements and the `<div>` in the middle.
3. We then let the middle `<div>` grow to fill the available space of
   the container with the shorthand property `flex: 1;`.

---

**Code Snippet:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, san-serif;
}
#parent {
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
p {
  font-size: 40px;
  background: yellow;
}
div > div {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <p id="p1">Long block that only appears on the top</p>
  <div>Maximising Div</div>
  <p id="p2">Long block that only appears on the bottom</p>
</div>
```

---

Notes:

- Check Michael's **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40031370/4305494)** for current browser support.

Comment: This'll do nicely, thanks to all the responses with the same!

Comment: You're welcome! Make sure to look for Michael's posts about `flexbox` here in SO. He's a great contributor in this subject, as in many others.

Answer (score 2):

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, san-serif;
}

#parent{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;              /* establish flex container */
  flex-direction: column;     /* stack child elements ("flex items") vertically */
  background: lightblue;
}

p{
  font-size: 40px; 
  background: yellow;
 }

#p1 { /* can be variable height */}

#p2 { /* can be variable height */ }

div {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1;                    /* consume free space in container;
                                 will force p elements to top and bottom */
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <p id="p1">Long block that only appears on the top</p>
  <div>Maximising Div</div>
  <p id="p2">Long block that only appears on the bottom</p>
</div>
```

***Browser support:*** *Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE < 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add prefixes use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).*

Answer (score 0):

Adding `width: 100%` to the `<p>` elements and setting `body { overflow: hidden }` to your current code provides the functionality you want if you can't use flexbox.

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
}
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, san-serif;
}
#parent{
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
}
p{
  font-size: 40px; 
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}
#p1{
  top: 0;
}
#p2{
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
div{
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <p id="p1">Long block that only appears on the top</p>
  <div class="maximising">Maximising Div</div>
  <p id="p2">Long block that only appears on the bottom</p>
</div>
```